# Why do we use Routes instead of Switches in React? Whereas our work is done by the switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import React from "react";
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"

import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    //BEM

    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        {/* Switch case */}
        <Switch>
          {/* checkout page */}
          <Route path="/checkout" >
            <Header/>
            {/* Header */}

            <h1>I am a Checkout, Smash the like button</h1>
          </Route>
        
          <Route path="/" >
            <Header/>
            <Home/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am update the code with the help of `Routes`, but my page is gone. So what do I convert?

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    //BEM

    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          {/* checkout page */}
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Header/>} >
            <h1>I am a Checkout, Smash the like button</h1>
        
          <Route path="/" element={Header/>} /> 
          //Here I want both page link in one path Header and Home.

          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand of your question you are trying to render a common `Header` component with each route. For this you can render the `Header` component on a layout route that renders also an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component for nested children routes.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import Header from "./Header";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            {/* checkout page */}
            <Route
              path="/checkout"
              element={<h1>I am a Checkout, Smash the like button</h1>}
            />
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
        </Routs>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

See [nested routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#nested-routes) in the documentation for more details.